# Issue integrating dojo and Spring JS

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dojo, spring-js

I am getting JS error and dojo not getting reflected

while developing spring MVC application along with dojo i am getting the mentioned issue. The configuration steps that i followed are below.
In web.xml below code is implemented for accessing the JS files/Resources present in springframework.js Jar along with other application configurations

```
    <servlet>
       <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.springframework.js.resource.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

In JSP the below code snippet is added for importing dojo library and supporting spring JS
files from JAR(springframework.js)

```
    <style type="text/css">
    @import url 
    ("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css");
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url    
            value="/resources/dojo/dojo.js" />"       
            djconfig="parseOnLoad: true"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url    
             value="/resources/spring/Spring.js" />">      
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/spring/Spring-  
                Dojo.js" />"> </script>
     <script type="text/javascript">dojo.require("dojo.parser");</script>
```

My doubt is like whether the imported JS files in JSP has to be present/explicitly downloaded into and kept in resource directory under webcontent or are those files present in the springframework.js JAR file? and will it be referred by ResourceServlet configured in web.xml dynamically?.

i tried with both options and still i am getting the JS Error as Object Spring is undefined.
i am using **spring decoration** as below and that is the place(**Spring.addDecoration**) where JS Error occurs(**Spring undefined**).

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({
    elementId: "userFname",
    widgetType: "dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"
    }));
    </script>
```

Please help me to sort out this

Answer (score 0):

org.springframework.js.resources jar file which contains dojo features(dojo.js,Spring-Dojo.js and themes) was missing. importing org.springframework.js makes available resource servlet. so both this jars were required and the issue is resolved